# How do I make my site mobile reponsive?

Tags: html, css, mobile, web, responsive

I tried searching on the internet for an answer and I couldn't find one that worked. I want to make my site responsive to mobile where the li elements become smaller on the screen when vertical. This is my code, I did put in a link to the style sheet where it is and did put the meta viewport part in the heading section.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
.list {
    width: 30px; height: 20px;
}

}
```

Comment: Your code works just fine. Take a peek (shrink the window and you'll see the red background go from full-with to 30px wide): https://jsfiddle.net/0tz6udt0/

Answer (score 0):

Here are some common standard points:

```
@media (min-width: 320px) { /* for iPhones and smartphones */ }
@media (min-width: 481px) { /* for larger phones and small tablets */ }
@media (min-width: 600px) { /* for tablets */ }
```

To be honest, it would be really helpful if there was such thing as `@media (min-size: iPhone)` or `@media (min-size: windows_tablet)`; it would make it a whole lot easier.

Comment: Where would I put that? In place of the @media only screen and (max-width: 400px)?

Comment: Like [ceejayoz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1902010/ceejayoz) said, your code works perfectly fine. You would put the element you want to edit within the `@media` block. For example: `@media (min-size: 400px) { .list { 
 width: 50px; } }` would work.

Comment: I saw in some tutorials that they had specifically linked to the @media in the <head> section, do I need to do that, if so, how would I do that?

Comment: There are two ways to embed CSS files to HTML files: You can externally link your .css file to your HTML code, or you can use `<style>` tags to do the same job. If you want to link the `@media` in the `<head>` section, you would have to put the `<style>` tags *inside* the `<head>` section, and then add the `@media` Click [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_howto_external) to see an example for external CSS files, and click [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_style) to see how to use `<style>` tags.